# How to store image as BLOB type on MySql from XML through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xml-parsing, image-uploading

I have one XML file in which image data is like this

```
  <vehicle_data>
    <vehicles>
      <vehicle>
        <brand>BMW</brand>
        <media>
          <images>
            <image>
              <local>D14591069439.JPG</local>
              <position>1</position>
            </image>
            <image>
              <local>D14591069447.JPG</local>
              <position>2</position>
            </image>
          </images>
        </media>
      </vehicle>
    </vehicles>
  </vehicle_data>
```

I have to access each vehicle and its data one by one, which is done through this...

```
$data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local
```

All images location are at the same place where XML file is placed.

Now I have to save these images on mysql as BLOB type...

```
$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,file_get_contents($data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local));

//$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

$insert_media = 'insert into images (image) values ("'.$info.'")';

$media_qry = mysqli_query($con,$insert_media);
$last_media_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

In above code the line which is in comment.

```
$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

This is actually working if I upload a file and save it as BLOB type in mysql.

But in my scenario I have just a name of the file + extension "D14591069439.JPG". which is string... !!!

Need Help!

Thanks in advance for cooperation.

Comment: The files your trying to load must be in a specific directory, so take the directory name + the file name to load the file.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: As @Jens suggested, your code is not secure and vulnerable. Now for your problem, are you able to log the `$data` variable correctly? Is it in right form?

Comment: @Jens Thanks, but I know about prepare statements. Right now I want a way to upload image file who's just name is written in the XML.

Comment: @Rohit Just now I have updated the same named variable... sorry for that... Could you check again !

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, exactly... its in the same directory where xml file is placed, 
just want to know how to load file without <input type="file"/>

Comment: Print it `$data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local` and verify the location. I guess, your PHP script is at the different location then your XML. Your code would be looking it in the same directory of itself.

Comment: $insert_media = 'insert into images (image) values ("'.mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local).'")';

If I do this... It will try to store string in image column which is BLOB type... ERROR will occur!!

Comment: `$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,file_get_contents($data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local));` Here this method `file_get_contents()` needs file objects `$_FILES[file][name]` something like this... But I want to put `$data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local` which is just a string containing image file name like this `D14591069439.JPG`

Comment: `$data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local` gives this output `D14591069439.JPG`

Comment: What is the location of PHP script? Confirm both should be at same place as you are calling the image name only. What code have you written to load XML?

Comment: _php files are at Xampp\htdocs_... **XML file and images are inside a folder named "data" which is on desktop.** I have accessed XML file and I can read each and every value from it... I am just not able to load image into database... from that name...

Comment: If I can get absolute path of the XML file which I have selected then It could work...
`$location = realpath($_FILES['xml_file']['tmp_name']);`
 and 
`$data = file_get_contents($location, $data->vehicle[$i]->media->images->image->local);` something like this but `realpath()`, `_dir_`, `_file_` they give path for server only... they dont give original path for the selected file from PC.